# gnuplot functions undefined octave

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I'm running octave on ubuntu xfce, trying to run a function to achieve the same as fill3 in matlab (not my own code) which uses:

```
__gnuplot_set__ parametric;
```

When the function is called, I get the error:

error: '**gnuplot_set** parametric' undefined near line...

I'm fairly new to Octave/MatLab and have tried re-installing gnuplot to ensure it's up-to-date, set the graphics toolkit to gnuplot both within the function and through the command line as well as trying:

```
gnuplot_binary("/usr/bin/gnuplot");
```

Which I was under the impression essentially told Octave where to look for gnuplot related things (As I say, relative newbie here!)

Any help greatly appreciated, I need this to work for some coursework!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not that gnuplot itself is not found, that's working fine. The problem is that the Octave function `__gnuplot_set__` no longer exists.

Whoever wrote your `fill3` function made use of `__gnuplot_set__`. This was an undocumented private function, to be used by internals of Octave only (that's what a function that starts and ends with `__` mean). That function no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I had read that 'gset' had been replaced by 
'__gnuplot_set__' but was unaware this had been removed. Is there an alternative syntax to this I could use to modify the code or would it have to be something completely different?

Comment: @Revilo I don't even know what that function used to do.  All I know from looking at the changelogs is that the function was removed in Octave 3.2 (back in 2009) because it was "incompatible with the high level graphics handle code". There must be a way to do what you want with the general figure functions, you just need to know what it is that you want to do and then make a new question.

Comment: fill3 was part of octave-forge "plot" and removed with https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/plot/ci/007b5944940a47c86f560c72a37eaab198657480/